# Plotly charts in Streamlit columns have excessive upper and lower padding

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, streamlit

My code looked something like this:

```py
with col1:
    st.write("## Above")
    plot_chart (figs[0])
    st.write("### Below")
with col2:
    st.write("## Above")
    plot_chart (figs[1])
    st.write("### Below")
with col3:
    st.write("## Above")
    plot_chart (figs[2])
    st.write("### Below")
```

And produced a web app that looked like this:
[image]

Does anybody here have any experience with Plotly/Streamlit and can help me figure out how to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!